# error passing data between ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitextview

I've a strange issue. I have a `UITextField` I can write inside and the text is displayed directly in `UITextView`. I'm using a `UITabBarController` to switch between the `UIViewController`. 
I'm using that class to save data (wrote in `TabBarController.swift`):

```
public class ModelData {

    var text = ""
    var color:UIColor? = nil

}
```

That code to save the data (wrote in `ViewController.swift`):

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    let model = (self.tabBarController as TabBarViewController).model
    model.color = textview.textColor
    model.text = textview.text
}
```

And that code to give the data (wrote in `SecondViewController.swift`):

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let model = (self.tabBarController as TabBarViewController).model

    textview.textColor = model.color
    textview.text = model.text

}
```

So, my problem is that: Because I use a `UItextField` where I can write inside I have disabled User Interaction in `UITextView`, but now I need to enable that options because I want scroll the `UITextView`. But now when I pass between the ViewController the data is not saved. (only the color is not saved)

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing.  Are you using a `UITextView` on both view controllers of the `TabViewController`?  Is user interaction disabled for either one now?  What isn't getting updated, the text, the color, or both?

Comment: 1. I'm using UItextField only in the first ViewController. 2. Now it's enabled U.I. on both V.C.                                   3. The color isn't updated  @vacawama

Comment: So you have a `UITextField` in `ViewController` that you write to the model, and then you update a `UITextView` in the `SecondViewController`?

Comment: I write to the model using the data of UITextView in ViewController. (Im using UItextfield to write inside UiTextView) and yes I update the textview in the secondVC @vacawama

Comment: How are you setting the color of the text in the `UITextView` of `ViewController`?

Comment: So the user enters some text in a textField, that text is written into a textView.  Then they change the color of the textView using a button.  Then they change to the second tab and the text from the first tab is there, but the color is not?

Comment: Yes ! @vacawana before I disabled User interaction and it working perfectly

Comment: I have 2 things for you to try.  First try change `viewDidDisappear` to `viewWillDisappear`? Any different results?

Comment: I've already tried,  same result

Comment: Try updating the color in the model from your button code instead of waiting until `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: @vacawama same problem..

Comment: Can you disable/enable user interaction and make it work again?  If so, can you tell me exactly what you are changing in Interface Builder and how?

Comment: @vacawama I've just tried to disable and write  `println(model.color)`  The result is with U.I. disabled for example (red color) : `UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.823529 0.133333 0.180392 1` and with U.I. enabled: `println(nil)`

Comment: Ok I've just find an error. in addition to disable U.I. I disable behavior Editable and Selectable.

Comment: If I disable the Editable options they don't save the data. But I need this options because the UITextView are not editable but only with UITextfield @vacawama

Comment: I finally am able to recreate your problem.  Why don't you just leave `Editable` and `Selectable` checked and turn off `User Interaction Enabled`?  The user won't be able to edit or select your text anyway because they aren't able to interact with the view.

Comment: Because I want to Scroll the textview so I need to enable the U.I ! @vacawama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, (it looks like a bug), the `textColor` property of `UITextView` returns `nil` when `Selectable` is unchecked in Interface Builder.  It is not a problem if the `selectable` property is set to `false` in code.  So a workaround is to leave `Selectable` checked in Interface Builder and set it to `false` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set selectable to false here so that the user can't select the
    // textview text, but User Interaction is still enabled to allow them
    // to scroll it.  This is a workaround for a problem in Interface
    // Builder which causes the textColor property to return nil if Selectable
    // is unchecked in Interface Builder.
    textview.selectable = false
}
```

Comment: @Mala, this works for my test project. If this works for you, please accept my answer and up vote it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, tomorrow I'll test your fix !